# Redirect input of running process

Tags: io-redirection

I know how to send a file as input when running a command like this:

```
./foo < input.txt
```

but how can I run `foo` interactively, and then after a while redirect it's input? Something like this:

```
./foo
CTRL-Z
fg < input.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix/Linux/etc you can do this:

```
cat /dev/tty input.txt | ./foo
```

Type Control-D (or whatever your EOF character is) to end the interactive part of the input.